Unable to Authenticate Azure Artifacts npm Registry in TeamCity
Description:
I'm encountering an authentication issue when trying to connect my Azure Artifacts npm registry to TeamCity. I've followed the steps below to establish the connection, but I'm receiving a 401 Unauthorized error.
Steps Taken:
Created an NPM Registry Connection:
In the TeamCity root project settings, I navigated to "Connections" and added a new "NPM Registry Connection."
Configured Connection Details:
I entered the following details:
URL: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com///_packaging//npm/registry (Replace , , and  with your specific values)
Authentication: Token (selected from the dropdown) token have full access in azure.
Tested Connection:
The test connection failed, returning a 401 Unauthorized error.
Applied Connection in Build Features (if applicable):
If I have a dedicated "NPM Task" build step, I selected the created "NPM Registry Connection" under the "NPM Registry Connection" option.
Build Failure:
When I build the project, the npm installation step fails with an error message
please let me know how to fix this 401 unauth error.

I tried adding Azure Devops Artifact via npm registry connection in TeamCity and it worked successfully
I have taken the complete url of my Azure artifact:-
https://dev.azure.com/xxxxxx0738/xxxxevops/_artifacts/feed/sidxxxxsai0738/UPack/testabcsilicon/overview/0.0.1

And added Azure Devops PAT token with full access in Access Token tab of Connection:-


Connection updated successfully:-

